# When to create cookies at client side(browser)

Tags: javascript, cookies

I understand the importance of creating cookies at server side , it is for transferring information between server and browser ,since HTTP is stateless protocol.

But I am not aware about why and when cookies are created at client side (browser).

Hope my question makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I am not aware about why and when cookies are created at client
>   side (browser).

Because if you want to save for example settings for the user you can use cookies. It might be easier as setting them in php `$_COOKIE` (serverside).

***BUT*** make sure it is no data which contains password or similiar - cookies can be shown in the browser

```
document.cookie = "name=value";

document.cookie = "username=smith";   // setting two cookies
document.cookie = "lastlogin=Dec 1 2045";
...
alert(document.cookie);               "username=smith; lastlogin=Dec 1 2045"
```

> JS has a global document.cookie field (which is a magical string with
>   odd behavior) when you assign into document.cookie, it actually
>   appends / concatenates a new cookie (an unfortunate syntax that does
>   not match the expected semantics of the = operator)

Comment: If user refreshes the page , still those values will be there ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be for many reasons. I use cookies on the client side to store non-sensitive information about the user that may be useful to know the next time they access the site.

For example if I am building a shopping website. I could ask the user to pick a currency and store that in a cookie so next time the user accesses the website I can read that cookie and set the currency without prompting the user.

Answer (score 0):

Often, client-side cookies is used to store **key** to extract stored information from database or other storage
http://screencast.com/t/mzvp9jTP